# camel splitter parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel

We have a service call which returns a list of ids with which we call another service which takes only one id at a time, so we are using the camel splitter with parallel processing turned to `true`. Now the call we make for the service is through a seda so we can put a timeout on it. This will cause the problem that parallel processing will not be parallel anymore since seda by default has only 1 concurrent consumers working on it.

Options:

1. put a ?concurrentConsumers=x on the seda
2. use direct rather than seda. (no timeout option?)
3. Any other option?

Of 1 and 2 which one would be preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly setting streaming to `true` on the splitter is useful for big messages. Which means it will split the input message in chunks. This reduces the memory overhead. So this will improve performance with large messages.

For a `seda` queue to truly process in parallel you need to set the `seda` route as follows.

```
<from uri="seda:report?multipleConsumers=true&amp;concurrentConsumers=16"/>
```

This will allow the route to use up to 16 threads for concurrent consumers. The `seda` component does not implement any kind of persistence or recovery, if the VM terminates while messages are yet to be processed they will be lost. If you need persistence, reliability or distributed `seda`, try using either `jms` or `activemq`

The `direct` component is synchronous and according to the documentation support for multiple consumers are deprecated. As of Camel 2.1: Direct endpoint does not support multiple consumers.

The other option is the `vm` component. The `vm` component differs from the `seda` component in that `vm` supports communication across `CamelContext` instances - so you can use this mechanism to communicate across web applications  Essentially the `vm` component is an extension to the `seda` component.

So if if you need parallel processing the `direct` component is not useful. If you need to send message across `CamelContent` instances then use `vm` if not then use `seda` as described above.