# Looking for concurrent exchanges as input to apache camel splitter

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, apache-camel, splitter

I am implementing a route to read rows from database, split them using splitter, process them in parallel and aggregate and update the database. Everything works as expected when there is only one input to splitter route. Sample code-

```
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:splitter"/>
        <log message="batch id- $simple{header.BATCH_NUMBER}, loop index - $simple{property.CamelLoopIndex}" />
        <split strategyRef="aggregatorStrategy" executorServiceRef="myPool">
            <simple>${body}</simple>
            <log message="batch id- $simple{header.BATCH_NUMBER}, loop index - $simple{property.CamelLoopIndex}, split index - $simple{property.CamelSplitIndex}" />
            <to uri="bean:gisResponseProcessor" />
        </split>
    </route>
```

When I send 3 messages to direct:splitter (each one taking few minutes to complete processing) and have them all be processed in parallel. When I try this, the first log messages outside splitter for all 3 inputs are printed immediately. However, the log messages from inside splitter indicate that each of the 3 exchanges is split one after the other. The submessages of each one do use the thread pool. Is there a way make the splitter split 3 input exchanges in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using a `seda` route or a `vm` route. Both these do the same thing but have slightly different uses. I would suggest you see this answer of mine about the differences: [camel splitter parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986860/camel-splitter-parallel-processing/22005165#22005165).

The problem you face is that you want to send the messages to the splitter in parallel. Thus message 1,2 and 3 gets processed in parallel. This can be achieved by using the `seda` component. The `seda` component is asynchronous and allow you to process message on the route in parallel.

Try this route:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:splitter"/>
    <log message="batch id- $simple{header.BATCH_NUMBER}, loop index - $simple{property.CamelLoopIndex}" />
     <to uri="seda:sedaSplitter"/>
</route>
<route id="sedaSplitter>
    <from uri="seda:sedaSplitter?multipleConsumers=true&amp;concurrentConsumers=16"/>

      <split strategyRef="aggregatorStrategy" executorServiceRef="myPool">
          <simple>${body}</simple>
          <log message="batch id- $simple{header.BATCH_NUMBER}, loop index - $simple{property.CamelLoopIndex}, split index - $simple{property.CamelSplitIndex}" />
          <to uri="bean:gisResponseProcessor" />
      </split>
</route>
```

Note the messages are handled to the `seda` component route where the `MESSAGE` is processed in parrallel. You can make this even more parallel by including the `parallelProcessing="true"` in your splitter so the individual items in the split are processed in parallel.

Shout if you need more information.

Comment: When `executorServiceRef` is set, then parallel processing is automatically implied, and you do not have to enable that option as well.

Comment: I tried the route you suggested and still see similar log messages. I seems parallel till before the splitter. The splitter only processing one input exchange (split into many submessages that are processed in parallel) at a time. Do I need to configure multiple routes like sedaSplitter to get the parallel consumption of multiple inputs to splitter?

Answer (score 0):

Check there is at least 6 threads available in your thread pool called `myPool`

Comment: Is this pool shared with other routes?

Comment: Not a shared pool. I will update the question with a complete camel config so it can be more clear.